# Using fputc() to write one byte

Tags: c, unicode, char

Given `unsigned char *str`, a UTF-8 encoded string, is it legal to write the first byte (not character) with `fputc((char)(*str), file);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the cast to `char`. `fputc` takes the character to write as an `int` argument whose value is expected to be in the range of **`unsigned char`**, not `char`. Assuming `(unsigned char)(char)` acts as the identity operator on `unsigned char` values, there's no error in your code, but it's not guaranteed to especially for oddball systems without twos complement.

Answer (score 1):

It's legal. `fputc` converts its `int` input to `unsigned char`, and that conversion can't do anything too unpleasant. It just takes the value modulo `UCHAR_MAX+1`.

If `char` is unsigned on your implementation, then converting from `unsigned char` to `char` doesn't affect the value.

If `char` is signed on your implementation, then converting a value greater than `CHAR_MAX` to `char` either has an implementation-defined result, or raises a signal (6.3.1.3/3). So while your code is legal, the possible behavior includes raising a signal that terminates the program, which might not be what you want.

In practice, you expect implementations to use 2's complement, and to convert to signed types in the "obvious" way, preserving the bit pattern.

Even if nothing else goes wrong, your terminal might not do anything sensible, if you write a strange byte to STDOUT.

Comment: The implementation is required to cope with negative input to `fputc`. The `int` argument is converted to `unsigned char` before writing, per the standard. The only issue is that `(unsigned char)(char)uc` might not be the same as `uc` for all `unsigned char` values `uc` (and it won't unless the system is twos complement).

Comment: OK, I never realized that `fputc()` expected a promoted `unsigned char` and `fgetc()` returned the same. Does that mean an explicit cast is necessary for `char c = fgetc(stdin)`, or are char-to-char casts implicit? (I know you should always check fgetc() against EOF as an integer, but ignore that for this question.)

Comment: @R, is there a safe way to cast `signed char` to `unsigned char` and back?

Comment: Actually, I'll answer that myself: `signed` to `unsigned` and back is safe. On the other hand, `unsigned` to `signed` and back is inherently impossible for some values on architectures that don't use twos-complement representation.

Comment: Oops. R.. is right, I misread the standard description of `fputc`.

Comment: And `signed char` to `unsigned char` and back isn't necessarily "safe". A conforming implementation must convert, say `(char)-1` to `UCHAR_MAX`, but then converting that big value back could raise a signal, clamp the value to `SCHAR_MAX`, or something else implementation-dependent.

Answer (score 0):

No, you have to pass a `FILE` pointer as second parameter. This is the file handle you would like to write the character to, for example `stdout`.

```
fputc(*str, stdout);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is legal. fputc will just write a byte. The cast to signed/unsigned in this case will just stop the compiler moaning at you.